# to create an trigger in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

i have a problem  that i want to create an trigger that checks the Pincode number 
is exactly six of digit or not.

please tell me an detail answer.

Comment: Please tell us a detail question first!  What is the datatype of the pincode column?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean a character column in your question, if so - you can achieve this without trigger but using check constraint like this:

```
create table test_1
(
pincode varchar2(20)
  constraint test_1$chk$id check (ltrim(pincode, '0123456789') is null and length(pincode)= 6)
);
```

Running these inserts:

```
insert into test_1 (pincode) values ('45sdgf65');
insert into test_1 (pincode) values ('4565');
```

Will result the error:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (ANDREW.TEST_1$CHK$ID) violated
```

But this one goes ok:

```
insert into test_1 (pincode) values ('034565');
```